# S3 direct upload with paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I want to upload files on S3 directly. But cant find a clear tutorial related to this.I find one tutorials but it doesn't clear to me

[S3 direct Upload](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and)

I want some help regarding S3 direct upload with paperclip

Comment: what is 'some help'?

Comment: There are many tutorials and resources online to show one how to upload images to to s3 using paperclip in a rails app. What is clear/unclear to one person will be the opposite to another. I suggest you start working on an app with this functionality and post specific questions as you progress. For starters follow the documentation on paperclip, https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip and search storing uploading images to s3 and see what you get.

Comment: I implement uploading on S3 but due to heroku request timeout after 30 sec I want to direct upload on S3. Need tutorial related to that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593268/s3-direct-upload-doesnt-upload-files............I upload another question kindly answer it if you know about S3 direct upload

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use s3 in whole project then follow below:

Add below code in any environment file like `development.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :path => "/resources/:class/:id_partition/:style/:id-:basename.:extension",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV["AWS_BUCKET"],
    :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  }
}
```

or

if you want to use it with specific model then follow below code:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
        :styles => { :small => "45x45#" },
       :path => "/resources/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_host_name => ENV["S3_HOST_NAME"],
        :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV["AWS_BUCKET"],
          :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
          :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but already implement this thing.I want S3 direct upload information

Comment: ok, then I think you have to looking into `http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and`

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/34593268/… upload another question kindly answer it if you know about S3 direct upload